# C++ Delete elements inside stack?

Tags: c++, memory, stack

I'm working on a basic text editor and I have 2 `stacks` named `undo_stack` and `redo_stack`. 
When the user exits, I want to delete every element(pointer) in each stack. What I've tried so far is...

The stack contains command(user command) pointers.

```
while (!undo_stack.empty())
{
  delete undo_stack.top();
  undo_stack.pop();
}

while (!redo_stack.empty())
{
  delete redo_stack.top();
  redo_stack.pop();
}
```

Is this correct? It seems to be working sometimes for me, which makes me wonder if the error is in my code or in clearing my stack. Thank you

Comment: "It seems to be working sometimes for me" A lot of the [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C++ work like that.  Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't, sometimes it might even wipe your hard drive.

Comment: why not using unique_ptr or shared_ptr ?

Comment: you don't say whether you're storing objects or pointers to objects in the stack. If the former, they will be deleted automatically when the stack is destroyed. If the latter, store unique_ptr<T>'s in your stack and you'll get the same result.

Comment: haven't learned about unique ptrs or shared ptrs in my class yet. What my stacks do right now..is when someone executes a command, that command is stored in the undo stack. If they do undo, then the undo command is popped and pushed to redo.

Comment: Its impossible to properly answer this question unless you show us how you have defined your stack.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're not working in a multi-threaded environment, your code for clearing the stack and deleting the pointers pushed onto it seems OK. Without more code and output it's difficult to know quite why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, but I would suspect one of the following:

1. The raw pointer that you are attempting to delete has already been deleted.
2. Some failure is happening within the destructor of your object which is unrelated to the stack per-se.

You could try to run it through a debugger and attach a stack trace.